# Cell Fracture gives deforms mesh

Tags: mesh, cell-fracture

I want to apply cell fracture to a (high poly) mesh. However, it gives me weird results: it deforms the mesh and gives me additional fragments which are not supposed to be there. When I delete them, they leave holes in the mesh. Thank you!

[image: Before Cell Fracture]
[image: After Cell Fracture]
[image: After deleting additional fragments]

Comment: Does the object have some thickness or is just a surface?

Comment: I wanted to asked the same... it just looks like a plane without any thickness. I'm quite sure this is why _Cell Fracture_ doesn't work correctly... I'm getting the same weird result with a plane, but when I extrude it and close the bottom it works correctly.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, it's a surface imported from world creator. There is no thickness!